# Replacing a jQuery Regex match by an eval on the found value

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, return, match

helpers, here is my challenge:

**Situation:** (simplified example)

I have a string in which there are different "parameters" marked with a certain syntax, depending on its "type", here "# and "[...]":

`myString = "There are still #numberOfDays days until Christmas and it is already colder than #temperature degrees! I also have still have to buy [nrOfPresents] Christmas presents."`

I have also different methods of mapping my parameters to values, either direct values or concrete formulas:

`myDict1 = {"numberOfDays" : 30, "temperature": -10, ...};
 myDict2 = {nrOfPresents: "nrOfFriendsAndFamily - boughtPresents", ...};`

**Question:**

Is there a way, for each parameter-type to select each parameter by regex and replace it with a return value from a function which takes the found expression as an input?

so far i got:
`machesForType1 = myString.match( /#[A-Za-z]*(\b)/g )`, but this only gives me the matches.

I would like to use something like `mySting.replace( /#[A-Za-z]*(\b)/g , computeParameterFromArrayInfo( [Whatever you find by using this regex expression here] ) )`

Any ideas?

PS: The number of different parameters is pretty high, so a separate evaluation for each parameter is not really an option.

Comment: Aren't you going to run into conflicts where your string actually needs one of these markers? They are fairly common. E.G `myString= "The phone # is #phoneNumber"`? Also have you looked into Angular?

Comment: I guessed that as long as i make sure that, with the markers, I only treat them as strings, there shouldn't be any conflicts. Would you maybe have any better ideas for marking something which sould be replaced?

Comment: Angular2 has a pretty extensive expression elevator, but it might not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by working around:

```
var myNewString = myString;

var foundParams = myString.match(/#[A-Za-z]*(\b)/g); // looking for all parameters with the marker "#"

if (foundParams){
    for ( var i = 0; i < foundParams.length; i++ ) {
        var str2replace = foundParams[i];
        var param = str2replace.substr(1); // here: removing the marker "#"
        var replacingStr = myMatchFunction(param);
        myNewString = myNewString.replace(str2replace, replaicingStr);
    }

}
```

and repeat this for each of the different parameter-types, adapted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a replace callback inside the `replace` method:

```js
var myNewString = "There are still #numberOfDays days (#no_replacing) until Christmas and it is already colder than #temperature degrees! I also have still have to buy [nrOfPresents] Christmas presents [no_replace_here].";
var myDict1 = {"numberOfDays" : 30, "temperature": -10};
var myDict2 = {"nrOfPresents" : "nrOfFriendsAndFamily - boughtPresents"};

myNewString = myNewString.replace(/#(\w+)|\[(\w+)]/g, function($0,$1,$2) {
  if ($1 && myDict1[$1]) {        // If Group 1 matched and there is a key with tha value
    return myDict1[$1];           // Replace with that value
  } else if ($2 && myDict2[$2]) { // Else, if Group 2 matched and dict. 2 contains such a key
    return myDict2[$2];           // Replace with the Dict. 2 value
  } else return $0;               // Else, just re-insert the matched value back.
});
console.log(myNewString);
```

The `#(\w+)|\[(\w+)]/g` pattern will match multiple occurrences of `#` + 1 or more word chars captured into Group 1 OR `[`, 1+ word chars captured into Group 2 and `]`. The match value, Group 1 and 2 are passed into the callback as `$0`, `$1` and `$2` (see `function($0,$1,$2)`). They are evaluated, and you may force any behavior based on what group matched. See inline code comments for more details on the logic.